# Update property on model if value exists in another model

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have 2 arrays of 'launchers'. A launcher is basically modelled as follows

```
struct Launcher {
  let id: UUID
  let title: String
}
```

My API returns an array of these launchers `[Launcher]` and I call 2 endpoints for 2 different results.

1. `userApi` returns a list of launchers a user has selected
2. `companyApi` returns a list of available launchers

I'd like to present the user with a screen so they may opt in or out of launchers. To do this I must be able to set the initial state on a UIButton so it reflects if they already have it or not.

I was thinking of adding a property to the model

```
struct Launcher {
  let id: UUID
  let title: String
  var selected: Bool = false
}
```

and then at the time of fetching the `companyApi` results, updating the property on my model to indicate if a user it or not. I will only ever be fetching in the context of the current user, so do not need to worry about multiple users.

How can I diff between `companyLaunchers` and `userLaunchers` and update the `selected` prop on the company model if this exists on the user model?

I was thinking something like this

```swift
company.forEach { cl in
    cl.selected = (user.first { $0.id == cl.id } != nil)
}
```

But this does not work as `Cannot assign to property: 'cl' is a 'let' constant` nor does it feel very intuitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Launcher` is a `struct`, your loop is assigning a copy of it to `cl` each time through the loop.  This copy is a `let` so you can't mutate it, and even if it weren't a let, you wouldn't be updating the value in the `company` array.

You can fix this by looping over the `indices` of `company` instead, and then updating the value in the `company` array through that index:

```
company.indices.forEach { idx in
     company[idx].selected = (user.first { $0.id == company[idx].id } != nil)
}
```

---

That said, searching for each `Launcher` in the `user` array for every `Launcher` in `company` is not very efficient.  Perhaps you should make `company` be a `Dictionary` keyed by the `UUID` (type `[UUID : Launcher]`).

Then you could update `company` by looping over the `user` array:

```
for ul in user {
    company[ul.id]?.selected = true
}
```